# Azure SQL Server Database

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-sql-database

We use SQL Sever as a Service in Azure cloud. Created WEB API and hosted on Azure Cloud under WEB APP. we are able to read from the DB using our WEB API, but unable to Write into DB using WEB API.  any clue ? thanks

Comment: for anyone to answer this, they will need more information about your web api, and any errors that you receive.

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log